# MonoDevelop/MonoTouch #if iPHONE?

Tags: iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm currently working on a multiplatform app for iPhone and various other devices, as far as I can work out I can use preprocessor directives to check if I'm building for iPhone or another platform, so for example I could have:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE
ScreenRes = new Vector2(800,480);
#endif

#if XBOX360
ScreenRes = new Vector2(1280,720);
#endif
```

However I'm not sure which declaration I'm supposed to use to check for iPhone, I've already tried IPHONE, IOS, I_PHONE and a few others.

Comment: I've posted an answer to a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37297511/5223160

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do not define any by default.   You can do this by adding the define yourself when you build it with MonoDevelop to your configurations.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of Xamarin Studio will provide extra defines to the compiler.

E.g. for Xamarin.iOS both `__MOBILE__` and `__IOS__` will be defined.

E.g. for Xamarin.Android both `__MOBILE__` and `__ANDROID__` will be defined.