# How to know the current OS / platform of the executing code (Android / iOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin

Using Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS, I need to now the current OS in a shared code section. Be it an enum, an int or a string, it doesn't matter.

I tried this:

```
System.Environment.OSVersion
```

Which is always "Unix" with some kernel version informations.

There are info on Android for example like

```
Android.OS.Build.VERSION
```

But it needs to be in the Android specific code section. 
Is there any way of knowing the current OS in a common library?

Comment: May I ask what you want to do with that info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the android sdk version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882883/how-to-retrieve-the-android-sdk-version)

Comment: @Daniel: my server (providing data and service) needs to know `who` is making the request (logging, push notifications, some specific data for the UI...)

Comment: @Andrei: nope. The question you're relating to is about Android only SDK version. I need to have a discriminant between Android/iOS.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can also try this and its probably the best solution I found :

```
if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    //iOS stuff
}
else if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{

}
```

Comment: Just to enhance this answer, one can also use Xamarin.Essentials with the DeviceInfo API. DeviceInfo.Platform will also return the platform, e.g. 'Android'.

Comment: this only works on xamarin forms, not on "native" Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.Android which is what the creator of the question is using

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [DeviceInfo](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/DeviceInfo) plugin.
It supports `Android, iOs, Windows Phone Silverlight, Windows Phone RT, Windows Store RT, Windows 10 UWP` and it works perfectly.

It can be used in `PCL` like this (you must add the plugin to the platform projects and to `PCL`):

```
var platform = CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform;
    switch(platform){
        case Platform.iOS:
            // iOS
            break;
        case Platform.Android:
            // Android
            break; 
    }
```

This kind of code isn't a good practice in `PCL`, its better to use `Dependency Injection` (this plugin use that) to customize platform specific behaviour.

Comment: Your link is dead

Answer (score 3):

Using reflection, try to retrieve the value of the `Monotouch.Version` property (and the equivalent for MfA: Android.OS.Build.VERSION). One of the calls will fail, the other should succeed; that's why you have to use reflection. That's for a real runtime check.

But as your app is compiled twice, you can fix that value at compile time.

```cs
#if MONOTOUCH
    var platform = "iOS"
#else
    var platform = "Android"
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for those solutions. I hoped another one exists. Those imply you to handle any new platform (aka windows) by hand. Not a big issue indeed but it seems strange to me that Xamarin does not provide suche service in its API.

Comment: Im using Xamarin iOS 9.6.2, Xamarin Android 6.0.4.0 and Xamarin Studio 5.10.3. The MONOTOUCH symbol don't exist. That #ifdef always go to the else. Yes im setting the iOS project as default. Any alternative?

Comment: too complicated