# How can I find out Android and iOS versions when running a Xamarin.Forms application?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way I can do that with a Plugin or do I need to write some kind of a custom renderer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know the current OS / platform of the executing code (Android / iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570878/how-to-know-the-current-os-platform-of-the-executing-code-android-ios)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios)

```
// Operating System Version Number (7.0)
var version = DeviceInfo.VersionString;

// Platform (Android)
var platform = DeviceInfo.Platform;
```

Comment: If someone wants to compare versions this could be used `if (DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 11) { // .... }`

Comment: Official docs link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-information?tabs=ios

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo` as well.

`Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo

Code: In App.cs

```
// The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 50,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                      new Label{ Text = "Id: " + CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Id},
                      new Label{ Text = "Model: " + CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Model},
                      new Label{ Text = "Platform: " + CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform},
                      new Label{ Text = "Version: " + CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Version},
                }
            }
        };
```

[image]

You could download the source code form the link for reference. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/DeviceInfoPlugin